# Image sorting by category

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sorting

I am trying to make an image gallery that lets the user sort options by category (land, sea, animal, and more). I wrote a small example.

***My goal:*** is that once the user selects (clicks) the category he wishes to sort by, the website will present only pictures from that specific category, while the other "unwanted" pictures will slowly disappear and move downward. Once the user changes selection, the "missing" pictures will reappear from below and go up until they reach their destination.

I did manage to make the in and out animations as well as keep the image hidden after the animation ends, but only after all relevant pictures disappear, the sorted pictures "jump" to their place instead of smoothly sliding toward their expected place.

Now I think my current problem is missing animation, but maybe I wrote something wrong in my CSS or my JS.

**edit** 
i think i wasnt clear with my goal here, i am trying to filter out all of the photos that are not belong to the category selected and then display only the photos that belong to the category that has been choosen stacked from left to right in order in that point im stuck the images disappear but does not stack smoothly

```js
const filterContainer = document.querySelector('.data-filters');
const photoItems = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-item');

filterContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  filterContainer.querySelector('.active-filter').classList.remove('active-filter');
  event.target.classList.add('active-filter');

  const filter = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');

  photoItems.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.getAttribute('data-filter') == filter || filter == 'all') {
      item.classList.remove('photo-out')
      item.classList.add('photo-in')
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('photo-in')
      item.classList.add('photo-out')
    }
  })

})
```

```css
.line-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active-filter {
  color: blue;
}

@keyframes go-out {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  100% {
    top: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none
  }
}

@keyframes go-in {
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  0% {
    top: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block
  }
}

.photo-out {
  animation: go-out 1.2s forwards;
}

.photo-in {
  animation: go-in 1.2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <section id='photo_wall'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12 data-filters'>
          <ul class='line-list'>
            <li class='active-filter' data-filter='all'> All photos </li>
            <li data-filter='land'> Land </li>
            <li data-filter='sea'> Sea </li>
            <li data-filter='animals'> Animals </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='land'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/807/200/200.jpg?hmac=Y8gayvNItiQYxP_Pd-2un9GH09XuyJdIZOQPw6K9QsI'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='animals'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/659/200/200.jpg?hmac=kFpdD3XTBGwPUAH1tD-AiWigstjIX8WGIcyySuVQIvE' class='animals'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='land'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/165/200/200.jpg?hmac=tQGrY9pm5ze9soSsZ5CNBt87zqnHfFwdPv_khau12Sw' class='land'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='sea'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/883/200/200.jpg?hmac=evNCTcW3jHI_xOnAn7LKuFH_YkA8r6WdQovmsyoM1IY' class='sea'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='animals'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/200.jpg?hmac=zHUGikXUDyLCCmvyww1izLK3R3k8oRYBRiTizZEdyfI' class='animals'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='sea'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/653/200/200.jpg?hmac=tZtho3csFdJ2rLHTTlT7WhXtDwbXgJNIIUvOQQb2dIo' class='sea'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Stating that you are new and stuff is just bloat and doesn't add anything to the question. Please be to the point. There is no reason to re-edit these nuisances back in.

Comment: I am not clear what the layout should be. For example, if land is selected should all the land photos bunch up or should they remain where they were in the first place?

Comment: that is exacly where i think all of the people who tried to answer my question didnt understood me, my goal is to re arrange them (stack them in order) by category so if i select land only land picture should appear on the screen and they should be ordered from left to right and from first row downwards (incase there is bunch of land images)

Comment: I can see how to do this at least in part when some images are to go down and disappear, but I don't know what you want it to look like when the user wants to go back to all images showing because how would a nearly-in-place image need to look when the two images either side of it are still moving apart?

Answer (score 0):

Not trivial.
Perhaps play with this

```
@keyframes go-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%); /* Move left by its own width */
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes go-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%); /* Start left by its own width */
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```js
const filterContainer = document.querySelector('.data-filters');
const photoItems = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-item');

filterContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  filterContainer.querySelector('.active-filter').classList.remove('active-filter');
  event.target.classList.add('active-filter');

  const filter = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');

  photoItems.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.getAttribute('data-filter') == filter || filter == 'all') {
      item.classList.remove('photo-out')
      item.classList.add('photo-in')
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('photo-in')
      item.classList.add('photo-out')
    }
  })

})
```

```css
.line-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active-filter {
  color: blue;
}

@keyframes go-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%); /* Move left by its own width */
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes go-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%); /* Start left by its own width */
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}



.photo-out {
  animation: go-out 1.2s forwards;
}

.photo-in {
  animation: go-in 1.2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <section id='photo_wall'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12 data-filters'>
          <ul class='line-list'>
            <li class='active-filter' data-filter='all'> All photos </li>
            <li data-filter='land'> Land </li>
            <li data-filter='sea'> Sea </li>
            <li data-filter='animals'> Animals </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='land'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/807/200/200.jpg?hmac=Y8gayvNItiQYxP_Pd-2un9GH09XuyJdIZOQPw6K9QsI'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='animals'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/659/200/200.jpg?hmac=kFpdD3XTBGwPUAH1tD-AiWigstjIX8WGIcyySuVQIvE' class='animals'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='land'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/165/200/200.jpg?hmac=tQGrY9pm5ze9soSsZ5CNBt87zqnHfFwdPv_khau12Sw' class='land'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='sea'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/883/200/200.jpg?hmac=evNCTcW3jHI_xOnAn7LKuFH_YkA8r6WdQovmsyoM1IY' class='sea'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='animals'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/200.jpg?hmac=zHUGikXUDyLCCmvyww1izLK3R3k8oRYBRiTizZEdyfI' class='animals'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='sea'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/653/200/200.jpg?hmac=tZtho3csFdJ2rLHTTlT7WhXtDwbXgJNIIUvOQQb2dIo' class='sea'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, u showed me a nice way of changing the animation that is even better than what i have done and i will use ur animation idea in my code but after the animation is over the picture stay in their original place and does not stack in order from left to right and that exacly is the problem i wanted to solve if u can review it once again please

Comment: Sorry, I did not manage. I tried to animate the height and width of the invisible images but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your event handling.
You have to condition it to your *list items* only.
You have to exclude `<ul>` and parent `<div>`.

```js
const filterContainer = document.querySelector('.data-filters');
const photoItems = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-item');

filterContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const targetElement = event.target;

  // Condition for <li>s.
  if ('filter' in targetElement.dataset) {        
    filterContainer.querySelector('.active-filter').classList.remove('active-filter');
    event.target.classList.add('active-filter');
    
    const filter = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');
  
    photoItems.forEach((item) => {
      if(item.getAttribute('data-filter') == filter || filter == 'all'){
        item.classList.remove('photo-out')
        item.classList.add('photo-in')
      } else {
        item.classList.remove('photo-in')
        item.classList.add('photo-out')
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.line-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.active-filter {
  color:blue;
}

@keyframes go-out {
  0%   {top:0px;opacity:1.0}
  100% {top:600px;opacity:0;display:none}
}

@keyframes go-in {
  100%   {top:0px;opacity:1.0}
  0% {top:600px;opacity:0;display:block}
}

.photo-out {
  animation: go-out 1.2s forwards;
}

.photo-in {
  animation: go-in 1.2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section id='photo_wall'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12 data-filters'>
          <ul class='line-list'>
            <li class='active-filter' data-filter='all'> All photos </li>
            <li data-filter='land'> Land </li> 
            <li data-filter='sea'> Sea </li> 
            <li data-filter='animals'> Animals </li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='land'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/807/200/200.jpg?hmac=Y8gayvNItiQYxP_Pd-2un9GH09XuyJdIZOQPw6K9QsI'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='animals'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/659/200/200.jpg?hmac=kFpdD3XTBGwPUAH1tD-AiWigstjIX8WGIcyySuVQIvE' class='animals'>
        </div>
         <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='land'>
          <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/165/200/200.jpg?hmac=tQGrY9pm5ze9soSsZ5CNBt87zqnHfFwdPv_khau12Sw' class='land'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='sea'>
            <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/883/200/200.jpg?hmac=evNCTcW3jHI_xOnAn7LKuFH_YkA8r6WdQovmsyoM1IY' class='sea'>
           </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='animals'>
            <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/200.jpg?hmac=zHUGikXUDyLCCmvyww1izLK3R3k8oRYBRiTizZEdyfI' class='animals'>
            </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 photo-item p-4 photo-in' data-filter='sea'>
            <img src='https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/653/200/200.jpg?hmac=tZtho3csFdJ2rLHTTlT7WhXtDwbXgJNIIUvOQQb2dIo' class='sea'>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i will consider that change in my event listener but your solution did not solve my problem, if u run the code u can see once the filter animation is over the images that should stay in the screen just "jump" to their stacked position instead of going smoothly to that location

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way of smoothly minimising the cols in the Bootstrap environment.

This snippet therefore uses just inline-block.

The elements always stay in the order they are given in the HTML, but when not on show they have width 0, meaning those elements which are on show will be side by side. And width is an animatable CSS property.

To get the falling image effect therefore the images are held as backgrounds to pseudo before elements of the parent divs rather than as an img element. These pseudo elements can be made to fall (and rise) without affecting the layout as they are position absolute.

They fall, then their divs are animated down to 0px width.

```js
const filterContainer = document.querySelector('.data-filters');
const photoItems = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-item');

filterContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  filterContainer.querySelector('.active-filter').classList.remove('active-filter');
  event.target.classList.add('active-filter');

  const filter = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');

  photoItems.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.getAttribute('data-filter') == filter || filter == 'all') {
      item.classList.remove('photo-out')
      item.classList.add('photo-in')
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('photo-in')
      item.classList.add('photo-out')
    }
  })

})
```

```css
.line-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active-filter {
  color: blue;
}

@keyframes go-out {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes go-in {
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  0% {
    top: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.row:last-child>div.photo-out::before {
  animation: go-out 1.2s forwards linear;
  background-color: blue;
  ;
}

.row:last-child>div.photo-in::before {
  animation: go-in 1.2s forwards linear;
}

.row:last-child>div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.row:last-child>div.photo-in {
  animation: fullwidth 1.2s linear forwards;
}

.row:last-child>div.photo-out {
  animation: zerowidth 1.2s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

@keyframes fullwidth {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes zerowidth {
  to {
    width: 0;
  }
}

.row:last-child>div::before {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: var(--bg)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id='photo_wall'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='data-filters'>
          <ul class='line-list'>
            <li class='active-filter' data-filter='all'> All photos </li>
            <li data-filter='land'> Land </li>
            <li data-filter='sea'> Sea </li>
            <li data-filter='animals'> Animals </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='photo-item' data-filter='land' style="--bg: url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/807/200/200.jpg?hmac=Y8gayvNItiQYxP_Pd-2un9GH09XuyJdIZOQPw6K9QsI);" class='land'>
        </div>
        <div class='photo-item' data-filter='animals' style="--bg:  url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/659/200/200.jpg?hmac=kFpdD3XTBGwPUAH1tD-AiWigstjIX8WGIcyySuVQIvE);" class='animals'>
        </div>
        <div class='photo-item' data-filter='land' style="--bg: url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/165/200/200.jpg?hmac=tQGrY9pm5ze9soSsZ5CNBt87zqnHfFwdPv_khau12Sw);" class='land'>
        </div>
        <div class='photo-item' data-filter='sea' style="--bg: url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/883/200/200.jpg?hmac=evNCTcW3jHI_xOnAn7LKuFH_YkA8r6WdQovmsyoM1IY);" class='sea'>
        </div>
        <div class='photo-item' data-filter='animals' style="--bg: url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/200.jpg?hmac=zHUGikXUDyLCCmvyww1izLK3R3k8oRYBRiTizZEdyfI);" class='animals'>
        </div>
        <div class='photo-item' data-filter='sea' style="--bg: url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/653/200/200.jpg?hmac=tZtho3csFdJ2rLHTTlT7WhXtDwbXgJNIIUvOQQb2dIo);" class='sea'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: this is very very close of what i am trying to achieve i did searched sinice i post this question and i found 1 webdesign who achieve what i wanted i will add a link but im not asking for an exact repica cause of copyrights but it is kinda similar to my idea
https://preview.themeforest.net/item/danny-web-developer-resume-html-template/full_screen_preview/19976830?_ga=2.158891576.363686731.1710782548-645364691.1710782548

Comment: What is it that isn’t right. I can’t see anything in the question that is different so I have misunderstood something.

Comment: actually i realized that i am idiot :) i am kinda new to all advanced css js animation stuff and i didnt read your code correctly and after playing with it a bit and changing the delays and the animation timings it is exactlly what i needed
i do want to add that i reviewed the portofolio part of the site that i linked in the  comment before and they use there something called MixItUp I i saw on google that it is JS plugin to make sorting filters
thanks for your help